# Pass class object to function (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

Sorry if this is stupid question, but I can resolve that

I have two classes

```
class A(
    val id: Int
)

class B(
    val id: Int,
    val className: String
)
```

Now I want to pass one of the object to function. I want to make "uniwersal" function.At the moment I have to make 2 function.

One with argument type as `A`

```
fun printClassFields(classObject: A){

}
```

And second with argument `B`

```
fun printClassFieldsB(classObject: B){

}
```

Is possible to make one function which accept both classes ?

Comment: Make B extend A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you want to do with the classes inside the function, but here are some options.

You could use an `interface` for all common fields:

```
interface Common {
    val id: Int
}
class A(
    override val id: Int
) : Common

class B(
    override val id: Int,
    val className: String
) : Common

fun print(obj: Common) {
    print(obj.id)
}
```

---

Another solution, if you know all the types, is to hardcode the function like:

```
fun print(obj: Any) {
    when (obj) {
        is A -> { /* handle class A */ }
        is B -> { /* handle class B */ }
    }
}
```

Here you'll get the `Smart Cast` from Kotlin and will have access to the fields of each class. However you open the function up to be called with anything as input which may not be desirable.

---

Another option is to use a `Sealed Class`, where you get the `Smart Cast` but limit the parameter type.

```
sealed class SealedSuper(val id: Int)
class A(id: Int) : SealedSuper(id)
class B(id: Int, val className: String) : SealedSuper(id)

fun print(obj: SealedSuper) {
    when (obj) {
        is A -> { 
            print(obj.id)
        }
        is B -> {
            print(obj.id)
            print(obj.className)
        }
    }
}
```